# Detecting resizing of JDialog

Tags: java, swing, resize, jdialog

How can you detect when a `JDialog` has been resized?  (`WindowListener` would have been my guess, but that doesn't seem to have a resizing event handler.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using a [ComponentListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html):

```
YourDialog.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() 
{
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```